# Symfony functional unit test failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to test the signup method, however im getting this on the logs.

> [2018-08-30 00:13:50] request.INFO: Matched route "signup".
>   {"route":"signup","route_parameters":{"_route":"signup","_controller":"App\Controller\UserController::signup"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/signup","method":"POST"}
>   [] [2018-08-30 00:13:50] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage
>   with an anonymous Token. [] [] [2018-08-30 00:13:50] doctrine.DEBUG:
>   "START TRANSACTION" [] [] [2018-08-30 00:13:50] doctrine.DEBUG:
>   "ROLLBACK" [] [] [2018-08-30 00:13:50] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP
>   Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: "An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (email, username,
>   is_active, password, roles) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)':  SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1 no such table: user" at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php
>   line 63 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException(code: 0): An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (email, username,
>   is_active, password, roles) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?)':\n\nSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php:63,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1 no such table: user at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:82,
>   PDOException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such
>   table: user at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:80)"}
>   []

and this as an error

`Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200.`

**SignUpControllerTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

class SignUpControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testUserCreate()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/signup', [], [], [], json_encode([
            'user' => [
                'username' => 'chuck_norris',
                'password' => 'foobar',
                'email' => 'chuck@norris.com',
                'roles' => 'ROLE_USER'
            ],
        ]));
        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());
        $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('user', $data);
        $this->assertSame('chuck@norris.com', $data['user']['email']);
        $this->assertSame('chuck_norris', $data['user']['username']);

    }
```

**UserController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/signup", name="signup")
 */

public function signup(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder )
{
    $user = new User();

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user->setEmail($request->get('email'));
    $user->setPlainPassword($request->get('password'));
    $user->setUsername($request->get('username'));
    $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
    $user->setPassword($password);

    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');



}
```

**User.php (entity)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=190)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
     * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // other properties and methods

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt and argon2i algorithms don't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getUser() === $this) {
                $product->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of entity User?

Comment: yeah one sec....

Comment: ok just updated i t

Comment: Look into database if you have a table named "user"?

Comment: «no such table: user» — clearly indicates there isn't one.

Comment: i updated the post, so u can see.

Comment: It is possible that you are using different database for unit testing. If so, make sure user table is present in testing database.